# Cannot SSH from school

Tags: ssh, port

I have 2 servers, one that connects to SSH via port 22, and the other connects on port 9450. Now my only issue is I can SSH to neither of them from school (I am using puTTy and FileZilla)!

This prevents me from showing my professors what I am up to in source code and I cannot edit my site in case of a major bug (it has caused crashes before). My professors have no issue if I can find a way to SSH but I have been trying to find a solution, I can find nothing.

I could use an online client but there are 2 issues with that:

1. They go for very short sessions and you have to keep filling out captchas.
2. I cannot use `Ctrl+` because my school uses Windows as their OS, not Mac OS.

What can I do? Can I do anything to get past the firewall - that is, without getting into trouble? Can I setup a proxy at home and then... what? How would I connect?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to the admins that run your school's network.

Comment: @Cheekaleak they cannot do anything, I have talked to them, its the overall school board which is state wide... not sure if I can get in touch with them

Comment: Is the problem that YOU cannot connect, or that your PROFESSORS cannot connect to have a look?  Why not "show" them via an HTTPS web site with login requirements for access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like port 22 is blocked. If you own the server, you can change it to listen on a port you know is open (such as port 80, 443) for ssh and then connect that way. This will also work if you want to use your home computer as a proxy instead.

Comment: He already pointed out that he has set up SSH on a non-standard port on his second server.

Comment: So??? Port 9450 is probably blocked. I said to use 80 because we already know port 80 is open (as he already confirmed he can use an online client, meaning http).

Comment: Ugh, sorry. Must have had a lazy eye here. You're right that could work. Can you edit your post so I can remove my -1, please?

Comment: @ryan so how would I change the port? Plus I have a HTTP server... so shall I use port443?

Comment: 80 MAY be open to non-HTTP traffic.  A proxy server intercepting port 80 may limit it to HTTP-like traffic (there is a program to carry a data stream over HTTP but needs code at both ends).  Try 443 (which MAY be open).  Some other common ports MAY be open.

Comment: @muqman edit sshd_config and add in another ssh listen directive. You should be able to add it to a new line and listen on multiple ports.

Comment: @skaperen other ports such as?

Comment: ryan, well i'll find out if this works on monday and then mark yours as answer!

Comment: ps why did my question get a -1 this is my first q here! (not saying it was you)

Comment: aww well, this would work if it wasn't my school :) but it still doesn't worn on my school.